# Optimizing code for the formatting of a row in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

Good day!

Now this is more of a syntax question for VBA, specifically when calling on multiple columns in a row. My code is used to give a format to a new row at each iteration. These iterations get progressively slower. I have already looked around a bit to find ways to speed it up, one which I have found and implemented being the Application.ScreenUpdating = False function which stops Excel from using considerable overhead. However, there is another area which I believe could be optimized. The following code is rather repetitive and calls cells individually which is both ugly and slow. Now, my problem is that I do not know how to use the Range function which would reduce the amount of code when I have the variable i in my loop...? Being a novice, I guess that I just am not aware of the proper way to use Range as I keep getting errors.

The code in question:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim EndRow As Long

EndRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 19 To EndRow + 1 Step 1

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Rows(i).RowHeight = 45
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 1).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 1).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 2).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 3).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 3).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 4).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 4).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 5).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 6).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 6).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 7).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 7).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 8).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 8).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 9).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 9).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 10).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 10).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 11).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 11).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 12).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 12).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 13).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 13).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 14).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 14).Borders.Weight = xlMedium
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 15).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(i, 15).Borders.Weight = xlMedium

    Next
```

Comment: Possible candidate for migration to Code Review SE?

Answer (score 2):

This will be a bit quicker:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim EndRow As Long
    EndRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flags").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:A" & EndRow).EntireRow.RowHeight = 45
    With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(EndRow, 15))
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Borders.Weight = xlMedium
    End With
End Sub
```

*As you see, no loops are required!*

Comment: This code doesn't call the right cells, probably because you didn't respect the .Cells(ROWIndex, COLUMNIndex) notation. It also does not allow for multiple iterations through a linked command button which the original did quite well. Gonna have to stay with the original for now and move on to  other stuff. Thanks for answering anyways.